# Call a linux command from php

Tags: php, python, linux, raspberry-pi3

I am working on a raspberry pi and I want to record video from a web page. 
I created a php file that call a python script. The python script record a video  of a duration of 5 minutes.
 The code of my php script:

```
<?php
shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /var/www/start_recording.py");
?>
```

The problem is when I execute this code from the browser it doesn't run it but when I execute it from the terminal by adding in the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

and typing

```
./myscriptphp.php
```

It executes the script without any problem!!!!

The code of my script python:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
camera=PiCamera()
camera.start_recording("video.h264")
camera.wait_recording(60*5)
camera.stopr_preview()
camera.close()
```

Do you have any idea what is the problem please??

I think that the php script doesn't wait 5 minutes untill it finish rcording

Thank you in advance

Comment: Premission problem probably. Check the permissions of user `www-data`

Comment: How can I do that please? I forget to mention that I execute it other scripts and it worked.

Comment: Please check the duplicate links.

Comment: I tried this: sudo echo "apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers but it doesn't work!

Comment: I guess the username is `www-data`, not `apache`

Comment: yes i changed to www-data but the problem persists. I think it is not a preblem of permissions because when I run the php script from the web a window that show the streaming of the camera appears and disappears quickly.

Comment: I solved the problem but creating a multithreading python script.